# What URI scheme should be used for a local concept in RDF?

Tags: url, uri, rdf, rdfs

Consider the case where you have some knowledge you want to name and you want to put it into a knowledge graph format like the resource description framework (RDF). However, you don't have an email, a web domain, or access to a namespace authority to [generate a URI for the RDF knowledge graph](https://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/URNsAndRegistries-50).

This rules out [tag uris](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4151), [cool uris](https://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/), and most other schemes, respectively.

Some possible options that I am not entirely happy with for the mentioned reasons:

1. http://localhost/myConcept but this implies a resolvable location. It might also still imply identical concepts for all interpreters of your knowledge graph.
2. file:///myConcept [file scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8089.txt) but this implies there is a resolvable physical location.
3. urn:uuid:f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6 [uuid scheme](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt), but this doesn't let you put a human readable component in the URI. It would be great if the uuid scheme allowed urn:uuid:f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6/myConcept
4. [Magnet uris](https://magnet-uri.sourceforge.net/magnet-draft-overview.txt) were envisioned to help communicate between local machines and the web. But they remain a draft, aren't well defined, and the examples reuse other schemes that depend on naming authorities.
5. data:,myConcept [data scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) but this also depends on registering a [mime type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#model), and as far as I can tell there aren't any mime types for abstract concepts. It also fails to encode any type of uniqueness such as would be the case with encoded files or communicate that this concept is only locally unique.
6. informal schemes like urn:sha1:, but these imply that there is some content to be hashed - and concepts with identical names but different meanings would get assigned the same hash.

What I am looking for identifies a concept in a unique way on a local machine that when communicated with others implies that the concept name can only be interpreted as unique in that single communication and may not be integrated with other knowledge graphs before being altered to be globally unique. It also doesn't rely on any namespace authorities or emails (which also require registration). Does such a scheme exist (maybe informally)? What would you do given the constraints?

**Edit:** Just want to clarify my view on emails and web domains. Emails are easy and the registration process is completely automated - you can sign up for one immediately. However, you are dependent on that organization to maintain the email registry, not kick you out (like if your email account is inactive), and not go out of business. Personal web domains require a subscription and it should not be required that publishers of data also pay an upkeep fee. This would likely lead to deregistration when they no longer want to pay the fee and the data can now become ambiguous if another user reuses those URIs for other purposes. Free web domains like yourName.github.io have the same issues as email addresses.

Comment: For RDF, did you consider blank nodes?

Comment: Great point @Stefan-broxIT-Solutions. I am not considering blank nodes because they are existentially quantified variables. And since RDF reasoners/query engines are based on first order logic, this prevents using blank nodes for predicates (classes and properties) as they cannot be variables (variables are restricted to terms such as functors and constants). Implementations may also limit whether or not part of a triple may be a blank node. See restrictions on object on this documentation of ARQ - https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/library-propfunc.html

Comment: Ah, for some reason I thought you need this only for ABox URIs. Makes sense!

Comment: Regarding your edit about the issue with email/webhosting providers: for using `tag` URIs, you don’t need to keep having control of the email address / web domain, and the provider doesn’t have to keep existing. You only need to control the address/domain at 00:00 UTC on one day. After that, whatever happens to it (you lose the email address and someone else registers it etc.), you can keep using the corresponding `tag` URIs forever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very interesting question! Yes, there is indeed a standardized URI scheme for local communication-specific resources ‒ [`cid:`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392), but I would highly recommend *not* using it for RDF, since you can't really expect that software designed to work with RDF will understand it. You could use it only internally, and you could convert it to `mid:` when the URI leaves your system, but why? That's not how RDF should work, it's better to pick a stable URI from the very beginning.

There are several factors that play a role in how a URI is chosen:

1. Should the URI be dereferenceable?
2. Is it possible that another person may pick the same URI for a different thing?
3. Is it desirable that another person may pick the same URI for the same thing?
4. Should the URI be "obvious", i.e. being used for what the scheme is used for?

Let's see what options are there based on these criteria:

### `http(s):`

1. Yes, `http` URIs are expected to point *somewhere*. For abstract resources, you can't find the resource itself, but at least its description. `http://localhost/` makes sense only if you run an HTTP server there.
2. As long as you have control over the authority, no other user is entitled (for some meaning of the word) to use it for their own purposes. However all users are equally entitled to use `http://localhost/myConcept`, since it is a *local* URI. It is not immediately obvious what this should mean in the world of RDF where URIs are supposed to be globally unique; you *could* assign a meaning to it but still you don't have full control over it.
3. & 4. are not really applicable here, since HTTP is used for any resource/concept in general.

For `http`, you should have a usable authority, and you should run a web server that can resolve these URIs, preferably as long as you intend them to be used, ideally forever. You can get one for free, but can you still use this if you don't want to? Yes!

- If you have a unique IP address, say `10.13.139.173`, you can use it directly as in `http://10.13.139.173/myConcept`, or you can convert it to a domain (see [here](https://uri4uri.is4.site/host.html/10.13.139.173)) and make `http://173.139.13.10.in-addr.arpa/myConcept`. You should still however have some guarantee that the IP address will never be reassigned to someone else, otherwise you will break point 2 (and 1 of course).
- Create an [`.onion` hidden service](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/onion-services/)! These are [standardized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7686.html) and unique, so you can use them forever for free, and be able to prove it, as long as you don't mind having a URI like `http://ofj09pokr8fypnybesnuuc62ygw12abxe2lapry3zgi2si8rvt61r2yv.onion/myConcept`.

### `file:`

1. `file` URIs should point to files. There is no resolution mechanism, but it is expected that you can open any `file:///` URI and if the authority is known, use some platform-defined mechanism to talk to the target computer.
2. The same thing as for `http` applies here. `file:///myConcept` could globally mean only something like "the file `myConcept` in everyone's file system", which is something you cannot use for your own entities.
3. Yes, it might make sense to use `file:///C:/Windows/notepad.exe` to denote a particular commonly used file, but this is not usable much in your situation.
4. `file` URIs are used for files. Using it for something else will likely lead only to confusion.

Using `file` URIs for abstract things other than files is a long stretch, and even in that case, you will have to solve the same issues as for `http` URIs, so it's better to use those anyway.

### `tag:`

1. Not really, but it is good to be able to contact the authority and find information about the tag somewhere.
2. No, in addition to the guarantees of `http` URIs, thanks to the time component of a `tag` URI, you don't risk into anyone else redefining what it means, if you lose control of the authority.
3. & 4. again not relevant, like for `http` URIs.

All in all, these URIs are much like `http` URIs but without the need to maintain a server that keeps them alive and well-defined. **I'd consider this the best solution** for the purpose of locally-used identifiers. If you can have a domain or email address at any point in time, it is enough to use them. You can use an `.onion` domain here too, so you'd have `tag:ofj09pokr8fypnybesnuuc62ygw12abxe2lapry3zgi2si8rvt61r2yv.onion,2023:myConcept`.

### `urn:uuid:`

1. No, URNs are not dereferenceable, they are names.
2. The UUID would have to be the same, which is extremely unlikely if you pick random UUIDs.
3. This may happen only if you use hash-based UUIDs, where it is desirable, but likely not applicable to your situation.
4. `uuid` URNs can be used for any resource in general.

You are actually incorrect about having a human-readable component in a UUID ‒ you forget the `#`! Say you pick `urn:uuid:e45f8769-8f64-4301-8c3a-12272eaa3f75` to denote your vocabulary, then there is really nothing wrong with using `urn:uuid:e45f8769-8f64-4301-8c3a-12272eaa3f75#myConcept` for anything you wish. Individual URI schemes *do not have control over the fragment*, so if the base URI is "yours", pick any fragment with any hierarchy you want. **This is the second-best solution**; it is shorter but doesn't convey the "local" meaning you wanted, and you only have control over the fragment.

### `data:`

1. Yes, a `data` URI can be locally dereferenced to the data it stores.
2. No, the given combination of media type and data is what the URI represents and encodes.
3. Absolutely, for the same reason as above.
4. Yes, like for `file` URIs, `data:` should be only used for data, i.e. a sequence of bytes intended to be interpreted using a certain media type.

Don't use this for abstract things which are not data. While you may get some uniqueness from a URI like `data:application/x.my.very.special.namespace,myConcept`, it's still fundamentally a sequence of 9 bytes.

### `magnet:`, `urn:sha1:`, `ni:` etc.

These are based on hashes, so if you don't have a hash, no point in using them.

There are also some other type of URIs that I am aware of, so let's take a look at them too:

### `urn:oid:`

OIDs have a hierarchy and you can get one for free to create your own hierarchy, and you could even use it for temporary identifiers with counters and other things. Otherwise it is same as `urn:uuid:`.

### [`urn:urn-5:`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-informal/urn-5)

This is a lesser known but cool informal URN namespace which allows you to use random bytes as identification but permits a local part, so (as far as I understand it), you can use something like `urn:urn-5:9Q8Vb+6gDOz6IpWyNnfKdVmA6gQ:myConcept`. The specification calls the part after `:` a "counter", but permits an arbitrary string if the resulting URN is valid, so you could use any path and any fragment too, of course (or `?=` for a sort of query). I'd say this is the **3rd best solution** ‒ it is completely decentralized and seems to be made for this purpose, has the parts you require, but it is not very well known.

### [`urn:publicid:`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3151)

This is another cool URN namespace, intended to be formed from SGML/XML PUBLIC identifiers. These don't have any particular mandatory structure (there is the FPI though if you want to use it), and I assume the system is "first come, first served" since you can pretty much use anything to produce these identifiers (or you can use [this tool](https://data.is4.site/uri)). I'd consider this the **4th best solution**, but again it's a bit obscure, and it's a bit "wild west" since (unless you use a verified FPI) you have to come up with your own sufficiently strong way of making sure the names you create are only your own.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Always amazed by how much work people have already put into these issues.

Marking as answered because it answers the original question and provides suggestions for alternatives. As to your question "why?". I guess I am still working through that. But the architecture I am envisioning involves multiple clients, who would need to register URIs. I want to confirm that if two clients creates a URI :bike that it gets checked to be a bicycle or motorbike before being integrated globally. The uri signifying a local scope would indicate that concept needed verification.

Comment: “URNs are not dereferenceable”—this is not a fact, they can be. “Yes, http URIs are expected to point somewhere”—this is not a fact, a lot (most?) RDF datasets use URLs that do not resolve anywhere and act merely as identifiers, apparently that does not violate the spec.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff Kinda, kinda not. You can find some information *about* the resource a URN identifies through specific resolvers (some are namespace-based), you may browse the vast [IANA registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-namespaces/urn-namespaces.xhtml), you may use some other protocols like WebFinger or just querying triple stores to find a description, but in general there is no single mechanism that a browser may employ when you wish to navigate to a URN, and certainly not `urn:uuid:` ones. When you have to use Google to "resolve" a URI, I don't consider such URI resolvable.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff On the other hand, `http:` URIs are URLs, they are meant to locate a resource, they have a well-defined resolution mechanism, they are commonly used for the purpose of locating a web resource, and the [best practice](https://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/) is to provide a resource, so I think I am well within my right to state that `http:` URIs are *expected* to point somewhere. RDF does not care, but if you navigate to a vocabulary item URI and it is a dead link, that certainly does not add to the vocabulary's credibility. Even for abstract things in datasets you should get to RDF.

Comment: “When you have to use Google to "resolve" a URI, I don't consider such URI resolvable.”
Then you’d have to admit that most IRIs in RDF nowadays are not resolvable, while being URLs. We can insist however much we want that they should be resolvable, but in reality they are not and that is explicitly OK by RDF spec. Apart from “official” RDF vocabularies and big players like Wikidata, I have not encountered resolvable URLs in RDF in real-life systems. In that sense they are even less resolvable than URNs, because you can’t even look up relevant URN namespace—a 404 page is all you get.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff Depends on what you mean by "most". Vocabulary URIs are by far the most common since every triple has at least one, unless you consider dynamic properties like https://sparql.xyz/facade-x/data/abcdefg (but that would be easy to remedy for the authors). If you speak about individual datasets, I admit I have definitely not seen the majority of them, but I have seen a pretty good share of triple stores offering descriptions of such URIs (Wikidata, DBPedia and other Virtuoso instances). All URLs on Mastodon are also resolvable.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff So if there is a big dataset with loads of unresolvable URLs forming the majority of unique URIs that can be found in all RDF graphs, or the majority of datasets have most URLs in them unresolvable, you may of course be objectively right that realistically you cannot "expect" to resolve 50 % of the `http:` URIs found in wild in RDF documents. But that is not what I meant - `http`(`s`) URIs are used in RDF precisely because of their universal resolution mechanism. Even if there is no server that offers the description right now, there could be and *should* be one in the future.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff So, to sum up, `http:` URIs are *expected* to point somewhere generally because that is what they were designed for ‒ you see a domain (corresponding to an IP address of a server), you see a path (to a file system), you see a query (to provide configuration for the server). The RDF spec is not bothered by any of that, but people certainly are ‒ if you use such an URI but without anything that at least mimics the above, you are doing something wrong and you should not have picked `http:` for the job.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff For example I have made a system that uses RDF when generating metadata for arbitrary files, and I have chosen to use prefixes like `data:`, `ni:`, `file:` etc. precisely because the URI schemes identify what they are used for, and it makes no sense for them to be resolvable through any server. If I picked `http:` without ever being able to fulfill the implied promise of offering some RDF description there (and I could ‒ see https://uri4uri.is4.site/ for where I do), I would be doing something wrong.